# Footer not sticking to bottom, and questions zoom on mobile

Tags: html, css

There's two problems I'm having, one is getting the footer to stick to the bottom, I've used the http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ solution but I just can't seem to make it stick.

The next problem I'm having is on devices where you can pinch to zoom on webpages, the content gets completely destroyed because of the left navigation column. Is there a better method to have the column like that?

CSS

```
body {
    border-top: 10px solid #C9CACE;
}

.headers {
    font-family: 'foglihtenregular';
    color: #1b88c7;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 54px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

h2 {
  font: 400 40px/1.5 'foglihtenregular';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 {
   font: 22px/1.5 'foglihtenregular';
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   color: #1b88c7;
}

/*-------Right Area-------*/
.right {
    padding: 0 0 0 270px;
    border-right: 10px solid #C9CACE;
}

.right, p {
  font-family: 'foglihtenregular';
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

a:link {color: #E48743;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color: #90CA77;}  /* visited link */

/*-------Left Area-------*/
.left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 248px;
    background: url('../img/bg.gif') repeat;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 10px solid #C9CACE;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#nav {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'foglihtenregular';
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0 18px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

/*-------Left Footer-------*/
#leftfooter {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 120px;   /* Height of the footer */
   text-align: center;
}

#leftfooter p {
  color: #d21700;
  line-height: 7px;
}


/*  
Sticky Footer Solution
by Steve Hatcher 
http://stever.ca
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com
*/

* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

/* must declare 0 margins on everything, also for main layout components use padding, not 
vertical margins (top and bottom) to add spacing, else those margins get added to total height 
and your footer gets pushed down a bit more, creating vertical scroll bars in the browser */

html, body {height: 100%;

}

.right {  }
.rightt { min-height: 100%; }

.main { overflow:auto;
        padding-bottom: 60px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */

.right_footer {position: relative;
  margin-top: -60px; /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 60px;
  clear:both;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #C9CACE;
} 

.right_footer_text {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}

/*-------Navigation Animation-------*/
@-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
  0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
  30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
  80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
.shake:hover,
.shake:focus {
  -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.shake {
  display:inline-block
}

@-moz-keyframes spaceboots {
  0% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  10% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  20% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
  30% { -moz-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  40% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  50% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  60% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  70% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
  80% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  90% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
.shake:hover,
.shake:focus {
  -moz-animation-name: spaceboots;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.shake {
  display:inline-block
}  

#primelist1 {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#primelist2 {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h3 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.main img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.intro {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

h2, .altheader {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.content-home {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.welcome {
  text-align: center;
}

.labels {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.labels a {
  margin: 5%;
}



/*Text Styling*/
.under {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C9CACE;
  width: 230px;
  color: #d21700;
}

.offer {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

/*Contact Form*/

#contact_form {
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

form.email p {
font-size: 15px;
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
margin: 0;
}

form.email input, form.email textarea {
font-family: 'foglihtenregular';
font-size: 15px;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

form.email input {
background: #f5f5f5;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
border-radius: 5px;
}

form.email textarea {
background: #f5f5f5;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
}

form.email input.send {
color: #fff;
background: #222;
border: #000;
padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
cursor: pointer;
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box; /*//to account for the border on top*/
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right {
    box-sizing: border-box; /*//to account for the padding*/
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

    height: 100%;/* //to let the child element fill its parent*/
}
.right-footer {
    height: 129px;
    margin-top: -130px;
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>About - Little Muffins Nursery</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<!--    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > -->

<!--[if !IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .rightt {display:table;height:100%}
  </style>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.gif" alt="Little Muffins">
        </div>

        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="shake" href="index.html"><img src="img/nav/home.png" width="215" height="38" alt="Home" id="nav_home"></a></li>

                <li><a class="shake" href="about.html"><img src="img/nav/about.png" width="215" height="38" alt="About" id="nav_about"></a></li>

                <li><a class="shake" href="curriculum.html"><img src="img/nav/cur.png" width="215" height="38" alt="Curriculum" id="nav_curriculum"></a></li>

                <li><a class="shake" href="contact.html"><img src="img/nav/contact.png" width="215" height="38" alt="Contact" id="nav_contact"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="leftfooter">
            <div id="colorfoot">
                <p>314 Kings Street</p>
                <p>London</p>
                <p>W6 0RR</p>
                <p>020 8748 4651</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
         <div class="rightt">
            <div class="main">
                <h2 class="welcome headers">Welcome To Our New Nursery</h2>
                    <div class="content-home">
                        <p>We are currently enrolling children from 3 months - 5 years on full-time and part-time basis.
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        We are open from 8am - 6pm Monday to Friday 51 weeks of the year. 
                        <br>
                        <br>We will also have a family club on weekends offering lots of fun and exciting activities as well as organizing your child’s favourite themed birthday party.
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        We hope you enjoy browsing our new website, but please bare with us, we still have lots to add.</p>
                        <h4 class="offer">Special offer</h4>
                        <p>We have a special offer for anyone who registers and starts in September or October, giving a 10% discount for your child’s first 3 months fees.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="right_footer">
            <div class="labels">
                        <a href="http://ratings.food.gov.uk/business/en-GB/580902">
                            <img src="img/hygiene_label_bw.jpg"
                                 onmouseover="this.src='img/hygiene_label.jpg'"
                                 onmouseout="this.src='img/hygiene_label_bw.jpg'">
                            </img>
                        </a>

                        <a href="http://www.ndna.org.uk">
                            <img src="img/ndna_label_bw.jpg"
                                 onmouseover="this.src='img/ndna_label.jpg'"
                                 onmouseout="this.src='img/ndna_label_bw.jpg'">
                            </img>
                        </a>
            </div>
            <p class="right_footer_text">Copyright &copy; 2013, Little Muffins Nursery. All rights reserved</p>
    </div>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome.  You will get much better answers if you include what you've tried (code) and what errors you see as a result.

Comment: Also it's better to ask one question at a time.  You can only accept one answer per question, and it also helps future users find the answers they need.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please copy/paste your CSS ?

Try this :

**HTML**

```
<footer>What you want into the footer element</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, your footer is bigger than 60px :) It's 129px, so your footer height and it's negative top margin should both be that (and you have a border on top, too, so that means -130px for the margin. You have it implemented for the most part, but you forgot a couple of pieces.

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box; //to account for the border on top
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right {
    box-sizing: border-box; //to account for the padding
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

    height: 100%; //to let the child element fill its parent
}
.right-footer {
    height: 129px;
    margin-top: -130px;
}
```

Box-sizing is supported back to IE8, and is supported in all modern browsers (with some browser-specific calls). Those fixes should make everything work like magic for you!

And as far as the mobile issue, I would say you can solve by setting a min-width of your page (960px is a generally accepted standard, but you can make it whatever you want).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what to do with that code, I've just copied and pasted it to the bottom of my css and the footer is fixed, which is fantastic! If that was all I had to do with it, then thankyou :)

However, the issues with zooming on mobile is still happening. The content on the right begins to fall underneath the column on the left.

Comment: You could try setting the `body`'s position to `position: relative;` and then take the left-nav to `height: auto; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;`

Comment: Hmm, that didn't have any effect either... It's such a shame because as soon as I get it sorted It means it's practically complete.

Answer (score 0):

Footer CSS can be tuned with fixed layout, something like this:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

In general, I suggest http://learnlayout.com/ as a great resource to learn positioning.